# Pine script, Identify the close of stochastic crossover below the previous close of stochastic crossover

Tags: pine-script

I'm a beginner of Pine script. I can only identify stochastic crossover. I just want to learn how to identify the close of stochastic crossover below the previous close of stochastic crossover. Thank you so much for replying! [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foXHB.png)

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay=true)
periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)

overbought = 80
oversold = 20

co = crossover(k,d) and k[1] < oversold
cu = crossunder(k,d) and k[1] > overbought

plotshape(co, location = location.belowbar)
plotshape(cu, location = location.abovebar)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`valuewhen()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen) is your friend for this:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay=true)
periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)

overbought = 80
oversold = 20

co = crossover(k,d) and k[1] < oversold
cu = crossunder(k,d) and k[1] > overbought
coLower = close < valuewhen(co, close, 1)

plotshape(co, location = location.belowbar)
plotshape(cu, location = location.abovebar)
bgcolor(co and coLower ? color.lime : na)
```

[image]